# CASE Statement in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, case

I'm trying to fetch data from table where I'm using a `CASE` condition in the `WHERE` clause and currently I'm using following query:-

```
SELECT count(enq_id) AS total, sum(purchase_amount) AS purchase
FROM temp_stock
WHERE purchase_date <> '0000-00-00'
AND purchase_date < '2012-08-01'
AND (

STATUS = 'Sold'
OR STATUS = 'In Stock'
OR STATUS = 'Ref'
)
AND CASE WHEN (

STATUS = 'Sold'
)
THEN delivery_date >= '2012-08-01'
END
```

But it returns `0` for `total` and `NULL` for `purchase`.

Comment: MySQL case statement in where clause could be used like this:
`WHERE n.status = 1  AND ( CASE  WHEN n.expired_at IS NULL THEN  1=1 ELSE n.expired_at > '${currUtcDateTime}' END ) `

variable currUtcDateTime could be `let currUtcDateTime = new Date().toISOString().replace('T', ' ').split(".")[0]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400574/cae-statement-in-sql-where-clause#comment16663862_12400635).

> I want to use Case Statement, could u pls clarify me about case statament in where clause

You can use `CASE` statement in `WHERE` like this:

```
SELECT count(enq_id) AS total, sum(purchase_amount) AS purchase
FROM temp_stock
WHERE purchase_date <> '0000-00-00'
AND purchase_date < '2012-08-01'
AND (    STATUS = 'Sold'
      OR STATUS = 'In Stock'
      OR STATUS = 'Ref')
AND CASE STATUS 
         WHEN 'Sold' 
         THEN delivery_date >= '2012-08-01'
         ELSE 1=1
    END
```

Here you need to use `ELSE 1=1`. otherwise you will not get desired result. For more explanation see [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff99b/36)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that CASE can work that way. What you want is a slightly more complex expression as your WHERE clause. Probably something like this:

```
SELECT count(enq_id) AS total, sum(purchase_amount) AS purchase
FROM temp_stock
WHERE purchase_date <> '0000-00-00'
  AND purchase_date < '2012-08-01'
  AND (
     (STATUS = 'Sold' AND delivery_date >= '2012-08-01')
   OR STATUS = 'In Stock'
   OR STATUS = 'Ref'
 )
```

Comment: Thanks Ian Clelland for reply, Your Query is working But I want to use Case Statement, could u pls clarify me about case statament in where clause.Thanks in advance