# syntax error in my select statement with Case in Where clause

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I have a select statement that I have been working on and I am getting a syntax error (Error Code: 1064). The part between ////////// in the query below is indicated has having a syntax error:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE 
First_name !='0' And
Last_name !='0' And

(Phone !='0' And Phone >= 10 And Phone Not like '111%' And Phone Not like '222%' And Phone Not like '333%' And Phone Not like '444%' And Phone Not like '555%' And Phone Not like '666%' And Phone Not like '777%' And Phone Not like '888%' And Phone Not like '999%' And Phone Not like '800%' And Phone Not like '877%' And Phone Not like '866%' And Phone Not like '911%' And Phone Not like '123%' And Phone Not like '1%' And Phone Not like '0%') And

Age !='0' And
Gender !='0' And

////////////////////////////////////////////

(Marital_status !='0' or Case when Marital_status = 'Single' then ((Age between 25 to 75)(Gender='Female' and Annual_income is between $40k to $200k)(Gender='Female')(Zip_code is between 90000 to 93099))or Case when Marital_status='Cohab' then ((Age between 25 to 75)(Annual_income >= 40000)(Zip_code is between 90000 to 93099)) or Case when Marital_status='Married' then ((Age between 25 to 75)(Annual_income is between $40k to $200k)(Zip_code is between 90000 to 93099))) And

/////////////////////////////////////////////

Annual_income !='0' And
Zip_code !='0'
```

Comment: Please share your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your schema is or your table structures are. I am not sure if this is what your trying to accomplish in your `Select` but your `CASE` statement needs to look something more like this in order to be syntactically correct:

```
or Case single when Marital_status = 'Single' then ((Age between 25 and 75) and Gender='Female' and (Annual_income between 40 and 200) and (Zip_code between 90000 and 93099)) Else 1=1 END
or Case cohab when Marital_status='Cohab' then ((Age between 25 and 75) and Annual_income >= 40000 and (Zip_code between 90000 and 93099)) ELSE 1=1 END
or Case married when Marital_status='Married' then ((Age between 25 and 75) and (Annual_income between 40 and 200) and (Zip_code between 90000 and 93099)) Else 1=1 END;
```

[Case Statement syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html)

[Case statement in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400574/case-statement-in-sql-where-clause)

[Between in Mysql](http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/between.php)